# ElasticSearch and Kibana images setup with XPack

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I tried to use official Kibana and ElasticSearch images but they just exit with error messages. And after a few seconds after launch the state of the containers looks like this:

```
     Name             State               
------------------------------
elasticsearch        Exit 1                                                                             
elasticsearch1       Exit 78                                                                           
mongotest_kafka_1    Up        
mongotest_kibana_1   Exit 1
```

The error message for one of the images:

```
elasticsearch1    | ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
elasticsearch1    | [1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
elasticsearch1    | [2018-06-04T09:37:17,274][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [L0Tp7dx] stopping ...
elasticsearch1    | [2018-06-04T09:37:17,289][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [L0Tp7dx] stopped
elasticsearch1    | [2018-06-04T09:37:17,289][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [L0Tp7dx] closing ...
elasticsearch1    | [2018-06-04T09:37:17,296][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [L0Tp7dx] closed
elasticsearch1    | [2018-06-04T09:37:17,298][INFO ][o.e.x.m.j.p.NativeController] Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started
```

I am not sure whether some configurations in my docker-compose.yml are wrong:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  kafka:
      image: spotify/kafka
      ports:
        - "9092:9092"
      environment:
      - ADVERTISED_HOST=localhost
  elasticsearch:
      image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
      container_name: elasticsearch
      environment:
        - cluster.name=docker-cluster
        - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
        - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      ulimits:
        memlock:
          soft: -1
          hard: -1
      volumes:
        - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      ports:
        - 9200:9200
      networks:
        - esnet
  elasticsearch1:
      image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
      container_name: elasticsearch1
      environment:
        - cluster.name=docker-cluster
        - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
        - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
        - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
      ulimits:
        memlock:
          soft: -1
          hard: -1
      volumes:
        - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      networks:
        - esnet
  kibana:
      image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
      environment:
        SERVER_NAME: kibana
        SERVER_NAME: "0"
        ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
        ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: elastic
        ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: changeme
        XPACK_MONITORING_UI_CONTAINER_ELASTICSEARCH_ENABLED: "true"
      networks:
        - esnet
volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
      driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs to be configured on the docker host (the elastic stack has some requirements above default Linux host installs). [Elastic has documentation on this process](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html), including the virtual memory settings. For this specific error, you can run the following:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

You'll want to configure this in /etc/sysctl.conf so the setting survives a reboot.